# Display single item from List

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to display a specific item from a list in ASP.NET MVC 4?  I am currently looping through the list and displaying multiple items.  But I need to break out of the loop and just display the REGISTER.UID from the list.

Here is the simplified code

```
@model List<INCA_RVS.Models.REGISTER>

if (Model != null)
    {
       <div>User ID</div><div><input type="text" name="userid" value="/* ListValueHere */" /></div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I need.

```
    if (Model != null)
        {
        var uid = Model.First(item => item.UID != "").UID.ToUpper();
        <div>User ID</div><div><input type="text" name="userid" value="@uid" /></div>
        }
```